# how to navigate back page with previously called web service data in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a basic app of windows phone 8.1, which is blank app;
I wanna navigate to my previous page without calling web service which I have previously called.
is there  any stack or any history method from that I can manage previous page easily .

```cs
 Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
 if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
 {
     rootFrame.GoBack();
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

this code is not working with my frames. because its send to me the first page from where the app start...

Complete Code

of course ----------------    Page 1 Design

```html
<Grid>
         <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Page 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            >
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Click to go to page 2" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel></Grid>
```

page 1 code

```html
  private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
        }
```

page 2 design...............

```html
 <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Page 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
       
    </Grid>
```

page 2 code---------

```html
public Page2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode=NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += Page2HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        void Page2HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (Frame.CanGoBack && Frame.SourcePageType.FullName == "Test.Page2")
            {
              
                Frame.GoBack();

            }
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
            {
               
            }
             
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
        }
```

page 3 design-----

```html
 <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Page 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
      
    </Grid>
```

page 3 code------

```html
public Page3()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += Page3HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }

        void Page3HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (Frame.CanGoBack && Frame.SourcePageType.FullName == "Test.Page3")
            {
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
        }


         protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
             
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
        }
```

please Replay.........

Comment: Can you provide more information and a more complete sample? The snippet you provided appears correct for handling the Back button press. Unless of course you've put it on every page (rather than globally).

Comment: thanks for your replay @Peter Torr....i have 5 pages, through them i have to navigate in complete app. which doesnt exist any sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**new answer**

You don't unregister your BackPressed event, but you still add them every time a page gets loaded, so it is executed multiple times.

Unregister your events properly.
Good place to do it in this case is the pages *Unloaded* Event.

You can also check out the *NavigationHelper* class theta is included in the Visual Studio Templates.

---

**old answer**

Every page has a *NavigationCacheMode* property and by setting it to enabled (works only in the constructor), you can preserve it's instance when navigating away.

```
public MainPage() {
  this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

Find the short desctiption [in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx#caching_a__page).

Warning: Caching and navigation/activation/suspension are a complex topic and I recommend reading into it.

Comment: Thanks Kai Brummund, i have this strategy, i have write  this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required; on constructor of the every page. and at created a handler like this Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            rootFrame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        } but still its not working... its navigate me to the start page............please provide me exact solution

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?
You are navigating to a second page, right? And pressing the back button brings you back to your first page, right?
Don't know what happens on your page, but if it was cached, it will just be displayed (and it's OnNavigatedTo gets called).
This will of course not happen, when your application was closed in between.
Also: Don't just cache everything. It costs a lot of memory. Cache your webservice result in your model and just let the page be recreated with that cached result.

Comment: thanks again....simply i have 3 pages page1,page2 and page3...i started from page1 of my app.. and then on next i opened page2 and on this page next button i have opened page3....now when i click on backbutton the app navigated to page 1 but it should back to page 2... for your info i wanna say you just that the backbutton is my hardware_backbutton. i have created handler on that for handling that event. and in that event i wrote the code which have you told me "Frame.GoBack(); and also e.Handled = true;"..........  but still its not working.......so please tell me problem resides that..

Comment: Yes it should. Could you provide you complete Code (navigation and back-handling)?